# Simulate Fourier Analysis with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

I'm trying to make a program that shows together the plot of my data and the plot of the simulated data. My data are from an RC circuit with square wave in input, shark fin waveform in output. The problem is that the simulated one is a little bit messy. I can't figure where is the error, I guess some is wrong on the frequency, but I don't know. Thanks to anybody who will help me.
Link to the data https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d8p9sIsNoVuXTsjHga0bXmgrbmUIb-LX
My code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

x, y = pylab.loadtxt('dati06_04.txt', unpack=True) #  $\mu s$; digits
off = (y.max() + y.min()) / 2  # digits, offset
Amp = y.max()-y.min()  # digits, amplitude
f_T = 24  # Hz, cut frequency
w_T = 2 * np.pi * f_T  # rad / s


def A_k(k, w):
    global w_T
    return 1 / (1 + k * w / w_T) ** 0.5


def Phi(k, w):
    global w_T
    return np.arctan(- w * k / w_T)


def c_k(k):
    global Amp
    c = 0
    if k % 2 == 0:
        c = 0
    if k % 2 == 1:
        c = 2 * Amp / (k * np.pi)
    return c


def w_res(tt, f, k):
    global off
    w = 2 * np.pi * f
    ww = 0
    for i in range(k+1):
        ww = ww + c_k(i) * A_k(i, w) * np.sin(w * i * tt + Phi(i, w))
    return ww + off


plt.plot(x/1000, y, color='blue')
plt.plot(x/1000, w_res(x, 111, 1000), color='orange')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When i call w_res(x,111,1000) 111 is the frequency in Hz of the input signal (you can see also in the first line of the .txt file, 1000 is a good value of k to have a good approximation.

Comment: What is the purpose of so many global variables?

Comment: To be used in the functions, are they not used like this? Probably I'm wrong

Comment: You can delete them, because you defined them above in the global scope anyways. Also it's hard to follow, because I don't know what your functions are supposed to do. I'd recommend adding some comments.

Comment: Writing  for example```w_res(x, 1/111, 1000)``` instead of ```w_res(x, 111, 1000)``` will show a sqare signal. I don't know that helps though.

Comment: @PéterLeéh oh damn, right. So why it's wrong to put 111? Still can't figure

Answer (score 3):

You probably confuse period and frequency somewhere, that causes your issue. I'm not sure where, because I'm not perfectly familiar with the theory, and I don't fully understand your logic there. The solution is changing the following line:

```py
plt.plot(x/1000, w_res(x, 111, 1000), color='orange')
```

to

```py
plt.plot(x/1000, w_res(x, 1/111, 1000), color='orange')
```

You got a straight line before, because the frequency was too low and you saw the lower edge of a square signal. Also, you can delete the global definitions, they are useless in this situation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where can I learn more about global variables and how to use them?

Comment: In Python usually it's a bad idea to use global variables, but there are few cases when they are necessary. I guess just google Python local global scope, global variables.